# How to use Azure Functions to fetch only new data

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Functions to periodically fetch invoices from a third party using its API and I'm looking for the best way to fetch only the new invoices.

Right now, my function fetches all invoices from the past day and my code makes sure that the rest of the processing has not been done yet before doing it. I'm 100% sure that there is a better way to do it. I'd like the solution to be robust, and this isn't. Is there a way to use checkpoints and know what was fetched or not?

```cs
        [FunctionName(FunctionNames.GetInvoicesAsync)]
        public async static Task<ReadOnlyCollection<InvoiceContent>> GetInvoicesAsync([ActivityTrigger] string name)
        {
            var begin = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
            var end = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var thirdPartyClient = ClientHelper.GetThirdPartyClient();
            return await thirdPartyClient.GetInvoicesAsync(begin, end);
        }
```

I'd like the "begin" variable to be the last successful execution of the function, or something along those lines.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to save an entry of the last successful execution in some sort of storage i.e.table storage. Then you could read table storage and order by Timestamp which would give you the last successful execution.

Comment: store _every_ response you get in table storage, build a project on top of that historical data with what ever you need to get out of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a small little code example of saving your function executions. I have used a HTTP trigger as it made it easier to test but the logic for table storage would be the same in your Activity trigger.

```
public class FunctionExecution : TableEntity
{
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }
}

public static class HttpTriggeredFunction
{
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("FunctionExecutions", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudTable table,
        ExecutionContext executionContext,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // query table storage for all entries (you might want to restrict the query to the last day etc)
        TableQuery<FunctionExecution> query = new TableQuery<FunctionExecution>();
        TableQuerySegment<FunctionExecution> data = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

        // get the last function execution by ordering by Timestamp
        FunctionExecution lastFunctionExecution = data.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();

        DateTimeOffset? begin = lastFunctionExecution?.Timestamp;
        DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // call off to ThirdPartyClient

        // log successful execution to table storage
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(new FunctionExecution
        {
            PartitionKey = executionContext.InvocationId.ToString(), // using the InvocationId of the function so you can relate executions if needed
            RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, // set the Timestamp to now as the function has been successful
            FunctionName = "HttpTriggeredFunction" // optional but you might want to save the function name in your case FunctionNames.GetInvoicesAsync
        });

        await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);

        return new OkObjectResult(null);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Had a thought - you might want to set the function name as the partition key to allow better partitioning (if needed):

```
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(new FunctionExecution
{
    PartitionKey = "HttpTriggeredFunction", // a partition is a consecutive range of entities possessing the same partition key value
    RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // row key must be unique within a partition
    Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, // set the Timestamp to now as the function has been successful
    InvocationId = executionContext.InvocationId.ToString() // optional - using the InvocationId of the function so you can relate executions if needed
});
```

Hope this helps somewhat!